# Captcha not displaying on dynamically loaded page (with jQuery)

Tags: html, recaptcha

I have a Google reCATPCHA (v2.0) in my website, but it's in a page that's loaded with jquery:

```
$('body').load("contact.html");
```

The page loads fine, but the captcha inside contact.html is not displaying, this is the code I wrote to add it (which worked in normal, not dynamic websites):

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfiXhwTAAAAAKbGwC23vNIz3_6A3sKZbH0R6muA"></div>
```

btw, I include the js script (re catpcha API) in the index, where contact is loaded:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit'></script>
```

How can I get the captcha to show up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261436/how-can-i-load-a-recaptcha-form-using-jquery-ajax-while-leaving-the-recaptcha-sc